# Passing js variable into php string

Tags: php, javascript

I need a little bit of help im trying to page a js variable into a url thats being parsed in php using file_get_contents. Im not sure where to start to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var js_variable = appl+goog+fb+mfst+nflx;
</script>

<?php
$ticker = js_varable_here;
$file = file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$ticker&f=soac1p2ghjkj1re');

?>
```

any advice is appreciated, like i said im in the dark on this one.

Comment: php runs on server and js resides at client. First it gets to server and than to client. You cant pass like that. You can use `ajax` though

Comment: use ajax to get the content you want

Comment: This exact question keeps appearing again and again...

Comment: is the js_variable set in your source code (which is what is in your example) or is it set on the client side (a more likely use case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using jquery.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var js_variable = appl+goog+fb+mfst+nflx;
  $.post("/somephp.php", {ticker: js_variable}, function(data) {
    // returned from php
  });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
   $ticker = $_POST['ticker'];
   $file = file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$ticker&f=soac1p2ghjkj1re");
 ?>
```

Comment: so the php part would go into the somephp.php file? just so i understand correctly

Comment: @Suzed yes. In this example, that's where the PHP would go. You can also change the url in the javascript to "./" if you are mixing html and php. (Which means you should probably add some logic in the PHP portion so that it detects a post request.)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Jashwant says...

PHP is a server-sided language, which does work behind the scenes. Javascript is client-side, which runs and executes code on the local client's machine (ie through the browser).

You can however use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) so the local client sends HTTP requests to the server without reloading the current page. For instance, you can use AJAX to send the contents of the variable to the server.

For easier usage, you should check out jQuery's methods regarding ajax calls. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hope it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Heres how you can do it with jquerys post() and then return json, you could build the result as you expect to output within the php part or you could use jquery to loop with each() through the result.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'
   && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
   && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){

    if(!empty($_POST['s'])){

        $ticker = $_POST['s'];
        $file = file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s='.$ticker.'&f=soac1p2ghjkj1re');

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('result'=>$file));
    }else{
        echo 'Request not allowed!';
    }
    die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
var js_variable = "appl+goog+fb+mfst+nflx";

$.post('this_script.php',{s: js_variable}, function(data) {
  $('#divResult').replaceWith('<div id="divResult">'+ data.result +'<div>');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divResult"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tested your code just to see if there was much of a difference and it doesnt seem to work, data comes back as undefined

Comment: Its working for me, have you changed **this_script.php** in the jquery post?

Comment: also you should see if $file contains anything. perhaps FGC is not enabled.

Comment: I changed this_script to / so it is working from the same file and if you change the js_variable it to goog, it should return values. but other then that nothing was changed